# Get Text from TextBlock in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

How it's possible to get in code behind Text from TextBlock when TextBlock is in DataTemplate? I know that correct way is to make {Binding} but i have no binding in my case.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ToggleDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_ToggleButtonContent" Text="Pause" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PART_ToggleButtonContent,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_ToggleButtonContent" Property="Text" Value="Resume" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="Test" Width="80" Height="40" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToggleDataTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //How to get text from Template?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's important to know why you want it; often it's better or easier to use MVVM concepts to do these things. You could navigate the visual tree until you find your textbox but it can get complicated and it's most likely unecessary...

Comment: A `DataTemplate` can be instantiated zero times, or a thousand times. Which instance do you want the text from, and why not just do this: `<ToggleButton x:Name="Test" Width="80" Height="40" Content="Pause" />`?